# Warning if docker containers are running

Tags: bash, docker

I was trying to translate a Powershell script to Bash.

The script is meant to stop the execution of any functions, if any of the container names specified in the parameters is already present in the Docker processes regardless of its status.

Bear with me as my experience with Bash is basic.

I got stuck in comparing the values of two arrays.

The first array is created using the following Docker command: `docker ps -a --format "{{.Names}}`, the second is a list strings.

This is the code that I got so far:

```
function __stopIfContainerIsRunning() {
    ContainerNames=("$@")
    allContainers=()
    
   while IFS= read -r line; do
       containerName=$(echo "$line" | awk '{$1=$1};1')
       allContainers+=("$containerName")
   done < <(docker ps -a --format "{{.Names}}")
    
    echo "Container Names:"
    for name in "${allContainers[@]}"; do
        echo "$name"
    done
    echo 
    
    echo "Container present:"
    for containerName in "${ContainerNames[@]}"; do
        containerIsRunning=false
        
        for name in "${allContainers[@]}"; do
            if [[ "$name" == "$containerName" ]]; then
                containerIsRunning=true
                break
            fi
        done

        if [ "$containerIsRunning" = true ]; then
            echo "$containerName is running"
        else
            echo "$containerName is NOT running"
        fi
    done
}

# this is how it's triggered
__stopIfContainerIsRunning "${containerNames[@]}"
```

It would be great if someone could review it and let me know what I am doing wrong.

TIA

Comment: This seems hugely overcomplicated, but Stack Overflow is not a site for code reviews. Perhaps try our sibling site [codereview.se]